# Route Attribute Web Api 2. Not routing properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to do a routing on my put but it is not working. I get 405 error.

My request

```
 return axiosInstant.put('/StorageItem/bought', {
            storageItemId: storageItemId,
        }).then(function (response) {
            dispatch({
                type: actions.STORAGE_ITEM_BOUGHT,
                payload: {
                    storageItemId: response.data
                }
            });
        });
```

Here are my 2 put methods

```
    [Route("put")]
    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult Put(StorageItem storageItem)
    {
        // return stuff back
    }

    [Route("bought/{storageItemId:guid}")]
    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult Bought(Guid storageItemId)
    {
       // return stuff back
    }
```

I am trying to hit the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second route is accepting a URL like `/bought/cf3221c5-6f76-4cf7-a70c-5c28e4a07322` and you're calling the URL `/StorageItem/bought`

You should modify your JS to the following:

```
return axiosInstant.put('/bought/' + storageItemId)
                   .then(function (response) {
                       dispatch({
                           type: actions.STORAGE_ITEM_BOUGHT,
                          payload: {
                             storageItemId: response.data
                          }
                       });
                    });
```